# Can I separate the settings of test to another pom file

Tags: maven, junit, pom.xml

To run my JUnit with maven, I add some settings into the pom file. But these settings are not necessary for my normal build and packaging.

Is there a way that I can separate these testing specific settings out to another pom file and import it to the main pom file?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of settings you have?

Comment: I add two settings, one to unpack a jar and copy the resource files, the other to add vm arguments for JUnit running.

Both are only needed for test cases running.

Comment: So to run your unit tests you have to have those arguments. This means they belong in the pom file otherwise no one can build your project without that settings.xml apart that those settings do not belong in settings.xml. Furthermore I'm questioning what kind of arguments do you need to run your tests? That sounds strange...